# elasticsearch aggregation by an array field

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, aggregate, aggregation

I want to use bucket aggregation to aggregate by an array.
Example documents:

```
1. {"arrayField" : ["1", "2", "3]}

2. {"arrayField" : ["1", "2", "3]}

3. {"arrayField" : ["4", "2", "3]}

4. {"arrayField" : ["1", "2", "3, "4"]}
```

In this example, there should be three buckets:

1. contains document 1 and 2, because they both have "arrayField" =  ["1", "2", "3"].
2. contains document 2.
3. contains document 3.

The regular terms aggregation divides the incidents to 4 buckets ("1", "2", "3", "4"), but this is not the aggregation I'm looking for.

I was able to implement this aggregation:

```
    "terms": {
        "script" : {
            "inline": "def total = ''; for (def item : doc['DESTINATIONS_ARR']) { total += (item + ',');} return total;"

              } 
     }
```

but I'm looking for a better / more efficient way. 
This should also work for arrays of numbers/ dates.

thank you.

Comment: One option is to store your array as a simple string object rather than as an array object but that would mean you will have to take ordering of array elements in the string as well. Otherwise, [1, 2, 3] and [2,3,1] will be considered separate entries.

Comment: heh, finally I found someone else having same 'crazy' idea/need. Did you solved this more elegantly?